# What does 'related tags' really mean?

Tags: support, api, related-tags

I'm confused when I use the api "https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/related-tags". I find that tag A is in the related-tags list of tag B while tag B is not in the A's. What's more, for every tag, the "has_more" field is false when requesting with "page=2" and so it indicates there is no more related tags. As a result, only up to 60 tags is "related" to one tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC, the related tags are determined by the tags most often seen together. For example, I would guess that [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) is a related tag of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) because most [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) questions have the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) tag on them.

This is a one-way relationship: although a lot of [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) questions are tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), a *far* smaller proportion of [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) questions are tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery).

To get some numbers:

- there are 1,086,048 [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) questions
- 370,448 of those are also tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) (34.11%)

whereas

- there are 720,375 [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) questions
- 370,448 of those are also tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (51.42%)

Comment: Thank you for showing me it is a one-way relationship. And  "related tags" or "tags most often seen together" is limited to 60?  I was wondering is there any official document about  the "related tags"

Comment: @StarLee I don't know about the limits for it. If there is documentation, it'll be in the API documentation at https://api.stackexchange.com/docs